# Group modules under same URL - CodeIgniter HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

I have some modules in CodeIngiter that work fine if I call them like this:

```
 - example.com/ControllerInModuleA/blaublau...
 - example.com/ControllerInModuleB/blaublau...
```

What I need to do now is

- example.com/api/ControllerInModuleA/blaublau...
- example.com/api/ControllerInModuleB/blaublau...

I've tried lot of things but I couldn't make it works.

Does anyone know how can I handle it?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your `APPPATH.'config/routes.php'` file.

Comment: I have the default one. I could use the /api/controllers way but I couldn't ban the original one.